# Query runs on mysql, but fails when put in Query Checker

Tags: mysql, sql, querying

```
CREATE TABLE T1(client_id int, Loancount int, PRIMARY KEY (client_id));


INSERT INTO  T1(client_id, Loancount)
SELECT DISTINCT C.client_id, count(loan_id) as LoanCount
FROM CLIENT  as C, DISP as D, LOAN as L
WHERE (C.client_id=D.client_id) AND (D.account_id=L.account_id)
group by  C.client_id;

CREATE TABLE T2 (client_id int, Trancount int, PRIMARY KEY (client_id));
INSERT INTO  T2(client_id, Trancount)
(SELECT DISTINCT C.client_id, count(trans_id) as Trancount
FROM CLIENT  as C, DISP as D, TRANSACTION as T
WHERE (C.client_id=D.client_id) AND (D.account_id=T.account_id)
group by  C.client_id) ;


SELECT DISTINCT T1.client_id, IF(Trancount>=LoanCount,Trancount,LoanCount) as Maxcount
FROM T1,T2
WHERE T1.client_id=T2.client_id;

DROP Table T1;
DROP Table T2;
```

When I try running this query here(https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/), it says an error exists around. INSERT INTO T1. The code compiles though.

Error Message:"You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'INSERT INTO T1(client_id, Loancount) SELECT DISTINCT C.client_id, count(lo' at line 6"

Comment: You really should be JOINing tables

Comment: Please ALWAYS show us the complete error message. A summary is never really any use to us

Comment: FROM CLIENT , you don't have that table.

Comment: Could it be `SELECT DISTINCT C.client_id, count(L.loan_id) as LoanCount`

Comment: @RiggsFolly We are supposed to find the table separately and then compute the max. If I join I assume the person has had a transaction and has a loan too.

Comment: What do you think `FROM CLIENT  as C, DISP as D, LOAN as L` is doing, but in a less predictable way

Comment: I also need the groupby

Comment: Also there are various types of JOIN https://www.dofactory.com/sql/join

Comment: PS You dont need the `DISTINCT client_id ....`  if you have the `Group BY client_id`

Comment: it still fails :'(

Comment: Can we start over? The existing query is nonsensical

Comment: I would go with mysql rather than the syntax checker.

Answer (score 2):

Are you pasting all the queries at once to the query checker? Most likely it accepts only one query at the time.

You can do the same with single query. No need for tables:

```
SELECT q.client_id, IF(max(q.Trancount)>=max(q.LoanCount),max(q.Trancount),max(q.LoanCount))
FROM (
  SELECT C.client_id, 0 as LoanCount, count(T.trans_id) as Trancount
  FROM CLIENT C, 
    JOIN DISP D ON D.client_id=C.client_id
    JOIN TRANSACTION T ON T.account_id=D.account_id
  group by  C.client_id
  UNION
  SELECT C.client_id, count(L.loan_id) as LoanCount, 0 as Trancount
  FROM CLIENT C, 
    JOIN DISP D ON D.client_id=C.client_id
    JOIN LOAN as L ON L.account_id=D.account_id
  group by  C.client_id
) as q
group by  Q.client_id
```

Btw, you should use temporary tables in cases where you just create table and then drop it after a query.